# Chrome API - What does the chrome.webstore API do?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I noticed a new API in the Chrome docs recently called [chrome.webstore](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webstore.html). The documentation is minimal and I'm not entirely sure what it's supposed to do.

What I hope it does is to let me do is do an inline install of another chrome webstore application, kind of like what's described [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation). So if I wanted my application to have a complementary part that isn't possible with optional permissions (e.g. replacing the new tab page), I could let them easily install another extension.

Unfortunately I can't really test this because I don't have an extension in the webstore yet, and I don't think I can use a random extension because it verified the link on the back-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API lets you install an extension inside another page that isn't through the Webstore directly.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation

Comment: Very dumb of me, I actually saw that page, but didn't make the connection. 

I thought the chrome API was mostly for extensions and apps, though I guess parts of it can be used by websites in general, which seems to be the case here.